# custom Python Module can not re-excute when raise exception in module

Tags: spring-xd

i custom a processor Python Module, RabbitMQ as source, Python Module can not re-excute when raise exception in python modules. 
in this python module, it connect to elasticsearch , when es is down, it raise exception 。 xd always get message from RabbitMQ, and  throw exception even elasticsearch service is available again:

```
2015-04-23 19:27:52,336 1.1.1.RELEASE ERROR SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1    process.ShellCommandProcessor - 
java.io.IOException: 
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:315)`
```

but otherwise in java processor module, when elasticsearch service is down,throw exception, but java processor module execute right while elasticsearch service is available again.

i respect service do not start depend others. so how to make python module reacton right  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created an issue to investigate this. https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-2982